# import JSON in Realm

Tags: json, swift, realm

I have a SQL Database on Azure and I would like to synchronize it with Realm, for my iOS App (in Swift)
For that, I have created a REST API which generates a JSON and now I would like to integrate this JSON in Realm.
To do that, I have tried to follow the explanation on Realm Documentation, so now I have :

Realm Table :

```
class tbl_test: Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var name:String = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Swift Code :

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let stringTxt:String = "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"My Name\"}]"
var myData = NSData()

if let dataFromString = stringTxt.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let jsonData = JSON(data: dataFromString)
    if let encryptedData:NSData = try! jsonData.rawData() {
                myData = encryptedData
    }       
}

try! realm.write {
   let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            realm.create(tbl_test.self, value: json, update: true)
}
```

I use SwiftyJSON to convert my string to JSON.

When I run the program, I have this error message :

> [__NSCFDictionary longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fdcc8785820 2016-07-06 10:25:30.090
>   mydrawing[9436:2732447] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcc8785820'

Is it a good way to import JSON in Realm ? There is no official way according to what I have found, but this method should work...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that the structure of the data you're passing to [`Realm.create(_:value:update:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRxCS_6ObjectrFTMx5valuePs9AnyObject_6updateSb_x) doesn't match what the method expects. It expects either a dictionary with keys corresponding to the managed properties on your model type, or an array with one element for each managed property.

After deserializing the JSON data, `json` looks like so:

```
(
        {
        id = 1;
        name = "My Name";
    }
)
```

That is an array containing a single element that is an dictionary. When you pass this array to `Realm.create(_:value:update:)`, Realm expects the first element of the array to be the value to use as the `id` property on your `tbl_test` type.

I suspect that what you mean to do is to call `Realm.create` on each of the elements of the array in turn, instead of calling it on the array itself.

Comment: Thank you bdash for your answer. It nearly works. Actually I have replace realm.create(tbl_test.self, value: json, update: true) by realm.create(tbl_test.self, value: json[0], update: true)  and now, I no longer have errors.So it seems to work, but my Realm DB is still empty. Is there something else to do ?

Comment: @Adz Were you able to figure out how to populate the Realm DB?

Comment: But my json contain inner sub arrays then how i will do this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380522/add-array-of-json-which-contain-inner-array-in-realm-using-swift